# Google Sheet: Prevent deletion of check boxes by users except the owner of the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with check boxes (Tick marks) in column I (I2:I50)
Since the sheet is shared with other users, i want that the check boxes are not intentionally or unintentionally deleted by other users of the sheet. Only I (sheet owner) can delete the check boxes.

Want to know whether its possible through built in range protection feature of google sheets or it needs Apps Script coding. If script coding is required, kindly someone please help.
Thanks and best regards

Comment: Are you currently using an onEdit trigger for that sheet?

Comment: yes i am using onEdit trigger in my sheet for timestamping when checkbox is ticked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an onEdit trigger already running try this.
This will replace the checkbox if it's deleted.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry1");
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 9 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == null) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1")
    e.range.insertCheckboxes().setValue(e.oldValue);
  }
}
```

This doesn't prevent users from deleting the checkbox but it does put in back to the same state it was before deletion and they can continue to change it's state as necessary.